# One variable with multiple acceptable values. Is this possible in Lua?

Tags: variables, lua

Pretty new to Lua.

What I would like to use because it seemed the simplest.

```
local IsJobs = {
      "job1",
      "job2",
      "job3"
      }
```

I thought I could just use or but that doesn't work how I thought it would.

All three can be true at the same time. They all do not need to be present but anyone of them can be accepted as true to allow access. But the others have to stay true after one is used.

I can't seem to make it work though. I have tried a few things to make this work but I keep coming up with empty. The program loads and runs but will either stop at the first string and not read the next or not read them at all. The tutorials don't seem to say I can but when I try to use a function it won't read the strings either. If I put the function in the online Lua compiler and tell it to print it will print the name or a table name but it won't read inside the table.

Three ways it's used.

```
if localxPlayer.job.name ==  IsJobs then

while localxPlayer.job.name == IsJobs do

function IsMechanic()
return localxPlayer.job.name == IsJobs
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are indentations not allowed in lua?
please indent anything between braces and function and end, and anywhere else = easier to read - for you and us - to understand and maybe help.

Comment: As far as I can tell Lua doesn't care about indents but I indented the variables in the table @iAmOren

Comment: I'll re-indent all...
I'm glad Lua and most other languages don't care about indentation as it doesn't effect them.  But, I, you, and possible answerers are not computers.  Indentation would help all of us - including you - when reading your older code/someone else's - and it's good practice.  look up conventions, pick one, modify to you taste if you want, and try to stick with it.  About your question - I'm sorry that I cannot help.

Comment: Indenting is not needed here. There are very few lines and indenting them won't help if you don't understand the language anyway.

Comment: Yep yep...  correct.  I over looked "Three ways it's used" and just saw the following code as something weird.  Should have split that to 3 code quotes.  Sorry to bother you...

Comment: Use a set and then do `IsJobs[localxPlayer.job.name]` as your condition

Comment: Hello - It is possible to use an table like an array in other languages. But you have to be straight and use only values as in your example and then you can count it with the #IsJobs correctly too. You can reach the values simply with a number starting with 1. Example: ```IsJobs[1]``` becomes "job1"

Answer (score 2):

```
localxPlayer.job.name ==  IsJobs
```

`localxPlazer.job.name` is a string (I guess). `IsJobs` is a table. So this expression will always evaluate to `false`.

`localxPlayer` is not a very good name btw. It looks like you forgot a space and intended to write `local xPlayer`. As most values in Lua are local I'd rather use a prefix for global names if at all.

As Nifim suggested in her comment you could use something like this:

```
local IsJobs = {
    job1 = true,
    job2 = true,
    job3 = true,
}
```

`IsJobs["job2"]` then is `true`

Alternatively you can do this:

```
local IsJobs = {"job1", "job2", "job3"}

local jobInList = false
for i,v in ipairs(IsJobs) do
  if localxPlayer.job.name == v then
    jobInList = true
  end
end
```